# Run dll method hidden

Tags: c#, dll, process, hidden

I am using a 3th party dll (jlink.dll) and things work great. The only problem is that jlink.dll will show a window sometimes. I don't want to show those windows. In other words imagine that the code of the dll has the method:

```
// some method on jlink dll
public bool OppenConnection(string connectionString)
{
     if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString)){
        MessageBox.Show("SomeError"); // <-----------------------------
        return false;
     }

     // some logic
     return true;
}
```

When I call that method from my program if there is an error jlink.dll will show a window and I don't want that. If the method returns false I can show a window myself. **So my question is how can I hide those windows?**

---

This is the solution that I have right now:

I have discovered that if I execute that method (OppenConnection) from a hidden process the window that get shown from the dll will also be hidden. The problem with this approach is that now I need one more process. One that is not hidden (my gui), another one that is hidden which calls that jlink.dll. I used namedPipes to exchange messages between these two processes. Things are getting to complicated and it will be nice if I could use one process instead of two. Also I have to have a separate thread that closes all the hidden windows that are created by jlink.dll. **It will be great if I could execute the jlink.dll methods just like the hidden process does from a process that is not hidden** That way I could have one process instead of two, remove all the named pipes and things will be much more simpler.

Comment: Did you try to start another message pump on a separate thread, create main window on it, hide that window, and then call jlink from that thread?

Comment: nice suggestion I think that will be easier thanks a lot! I think that will be a right solution did not thought about that don't know why...

Comment: Why don't you just make sure the `IsNullOrEmpty` boolean is never true?

Comment: that was just an example of the method. It does more complicated stuff... There is no way of me knowing if there will be an error prior to calling the method

Answer (score 0):

You want to call into a DLL you do not control to call specific portions of a method but not all of the logic within the method.  You have a few options: 1) live with it, 2) roll your own code based on the functionality you did want (use something like reflector), or 3) use something like reflector to see if there are any methods that expose the innards you did want so that you can do a combination of 1 and 2.

If I'm missing something let me know ;-)

Comment: True I don't have control of that dll. The message boxes that the dll show are dumb they don't do any logic. I think I will do what Fyodor Soikin suggested I dont need that extra process and the named pipes if I follow what he said.